# How can I ignore non-existing files in a fixed custom tags-search?

Tags: search, files, tags

I want to search through a fixed set of files and I use the `tags-search` command for it:

```
(defvar my-files-form
  '(list "/path/to/one/file"
         "/path/to/another/file"))

(defun search-my-files (regexp)
  (interactive "sSearch my files (regexp): ")
  (tags-search regexp my-files-form))
```

This works great when all files in `my-files-form` exist, but if, for instance, `/path/to/one/file` does not exist, then the command fails mid-search and will never look through the existing second file `/path/to/another/file`.

How can I ignore non-existing files in the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the list with `file-exists-p` before passing it to `tag-search` to ignore non-existent files.

```lisp
(defvar my-files-form
  '("/path/to/one/file"
    "/path/to/another/file"))

(defun search-my-files (regexp)
  (interactive "sSearch myfiles (regexp): ")
  (tags-search regexp (seq-filter 'file-exists-p my-files-form)))
```

Note that I got rid of the initial `list` in `my-files-form`.  It's not needed, because you're already quoting the list of files.

### References

- [seq-filter](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Sequence-Functions#function-seq-filter-predicate-sequence) - This function returns a list of all the elements in sequence for which predicate returns non-nil.
- [file-exists-p](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Testing-Accessibility#function-file-exists-p-filename) - This function returns t if a file named filename appears to exist.

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thanks!